# Losing memory on each call to scalapack solve function

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel-mkl, scalapack

I am solving a large system of equations using scalapack. Some systems that should run with no problem failed, apparently due to lack of memory in an mpi call. After investigating with `execute_command_line("free -m")`, I found that I'm losing large amounts of available RAM after every call to PZGETRS. By large, I mean O(GB), but it varies based on the matrix size and also the number of processes I include in the scalapack context. After some number of calls to PZGETRS, I do eventually run out of RAM, leading to the error messages.

I created a minimum working example:

```
program main
use mpi_f08
implicit none

    integer(kind=4) :: ierr, commW, commM, num_tasks, icontxt, nprow, npcol, n, &
        info, sub, trow, ii, my_row, my_col, tcol
    complex(kind=8), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: A, BX
    integer(kind=4), dimension(:), allocatable :: ipiv
    integer(kind=4), dimension(9) :: block_desc
    integer, external :: numroc   ! blacs routine
    double precision :: t1, t2, tf, ts

    ! Initialize MPI and establish self
    call mpi_init(ierr)
    commW=mpi_comm_world%mpi_val
    call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, commM, ierr)
    call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, num_tasks, ierr)

    if (commM == 0) write(*,*) "Program start"
    if (commM == 0) call execute_command_line("free -m | head -2 | sed -e 1d")

    ! Initalize process array
    nprow = ceiling(sqrt(real(num_tasks,kind=4)))    ! Make grid squareish
    do while (mod(num_tasks, nprow) /= 0)
        nprow = nprow + 1
    end do
    npcol = num_tasks/nprow
    call blacs_get(0,0,icontxt)
    call blacs_gridinit(icontxt,'R',nprow,npcol)
    call blacs_gridinfo(icontxt, nprow, npcol, my_row, my_col)

    ! Set up arrays based on number of tasks and the small block size
    n = 6200
    sub = 40            ! size of block in block cyclic dist.
    trow = numroc(n,sub,my_row,0,nprow)
    tcol = numroc(n,sub,my_col,0,nprow)
    call descinit(block_desc, n, n, sub, sub, 0, 0, icontxt, trow, ierr)

    ! everyone allocate their data and fill with something
    allocate(A(trow, tcol), BX(trow, tcol), ipiv(n))
    A = cmplx(1.d0,1.d0,kind=8)
    BX = cmplx(2.d0,1.d0,kind=8)
    do ii = 1,min(trow,tcol)
        A(ii,ii) = cmplx(2.d0,2.d0,kind=8)
    end do

    ! call factor routine then solve
    if (commM == 0) write(*,*) "All of my variables allocated."
    if (commM == 0) call execute_command_line("free -m | head -2 | sed -e 1d")
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world)
    t1 = mpi_wtime()
    call pzgetrf(n,n,A,1,1,block_desc,ipiv,info)
    t2 = mpi_wtime()
    tf = t2 - t1
    if (commM == 0) write(*,*) "Post factor."
    if (commM == 0) call execute_command_line("free -m | head -2 | sed -e 1d")
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world)
    t1 = mpi_wtime()
    call pzgetrs('N',n,n,A,1,1,block_desc,ipiv,BX,1,1,block_desc,info)
    t2 = mpi_wtime()
    ts = t2 - t1
    if (commM == 0) write(*,*) "Post solve."
    if (commM == 0) call execute_command_line("free -m | head -2 | sed -e 1d")
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world)

    deallocate(A,BX,ipiv)
    call blacs_gridexit(icontxt)
    if (commM == 0) write(*,*) "Shutting down."
    if (commM == 0) call execute_command_line("free -m | head -2 | sed -e 1d")
    if (commM == 0) write(*,*) "Factor: ", tf, "Solve: ", ts
    call mpi_finalize(ierr)

end program main
```

I'm linking with MKL according to the intel link line advisor and the cluster documentation that I'm using. Some lines from my Makefile, Makefile.inc...

```
LMPI                 := -L$(TACC_IMPI_LIB) -lmpi
IMPI                 := -I$(TACC_IMPI_INC)
LMKL                 := -L$(TACC_MKL_LIB) -lmkl_scalapack_lp64 -lmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64 -lpthread -lm -ldl
IMKL                 := -I$(TACC_MKL_INC)
LCOMBINE             := $(LMPI) $(LMKL)
ICOMBINE             := $(IMPI) $(IMKL)
...
FFLAGS := -O0 -g -debug -mkl=cluster
FC := $(TACC_IMPI_BIN)/mpiifort
FL := $(TACC_IMPI_BIN)/mpiifort
...
@echo Compiling $<
@$(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(ICOMBINE) -c $< -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@
@echo Linking to executable "'$(MAIN_EXE)'"
@$(FL) $(FFLAGS) $(MAIN_OBJ_FINAL) $(LCOMBINE) -o $(MAIN_EXE)
```

(The full Makefiles are uploaded on my [question for the intel forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-HPC-Toolkit/scalapack-memory-loss/m-p/1445069/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufExDUDZTU0ZDOVlBN0RafDE0NDUwNjl8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw#M10235), currently unsolved).

After lots of tests, I've found the memory loss depends on the software I compile my code with. I would prefer to use impi/intel-mkl given how quickly that combination solves my problems. However, that combo uses the most memory. Using OpenMPI + open source scalapack (v2.0.0), my memory loss is much smaller (for example, ~7300 MB with intel, ~200 MB with openmpi), but my code runs significantly slower.

Intel documentation mentions that some buffers are not deallocated until the program shuts down, for speed reasons, and says to either set the environmental variable MKL_DISABLE_FAST_MM=1 to turn that off, or have a line in the code: `mm = mkl_disable_fast_mm()` before calling mkl functions to disable this feature. Neither option has worked for me. I used the memory probe functions provided by intel to monitor maximum memory use, and got back a claim that 11 MB were used when I watch my available RAM drop by 7 GB via the `free` command.

My question is why am I'm seeing this behavior? Am I compiling wrong, or using scalapack wrong, or is this an actual bug? Does anyone have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Also query the free memory after `MPI_Finalize`.